# Parsing nested xml with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am working on a javascript project which involves parsing xml data. I have an xml file of the following structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<newsmodule>
    <year name="2012">
        <news>
        <date>Jan 01</date>
        <title>title 1</title>
        <info>info 1</info>
    </news>
    <news>
        <date>Jan 02</date>
        <title>title 2</title>
        <info>info 2</info>
    </news>
</year>
<year name="2011">
    <news>
        <date>Jan 03</date>
        <title>title 3</title>
        <info>info 3</info>
    </news>
    <news>
        <date>Jan 04</date>
        <title>title 4</title>
        <info>info 4</info>
    </news>
</year>
```

I need to write every date for year 2012 in array. I used the following code:

```js
$(xml).find("year").each(function () {

...

$(xml).find("news").each(function () {
   dates.push($(this).find("date").text());
   titles.push($(this).find("title").text());
   infos.push($(this).find("info").text());
});
```

And for the obvious reason i've got data for all years in the same array.

Is there a way to get this to work? I may not change the xml file.

Comment: Would a function that converts XML to JSON help you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to traverse through the XML that is very browser dependent use [`parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), also if that is exactly the xml that you have posted that is malformed there is no ending `</newsmodule>`

```
var xml='<newsmodule>
    <year name="2012">
        <news>
        <date>Jan 01</date>
        <title>title 1</title>
        <info>info 1</info>
    </news>
    <news>
        <date>Jan 02</date>
        <title>title 2</title>
        <info>info 2</info>
    </news>
</year>
<year name="2011"><news>
        <date>Jan 03</date>
        <title>title 3</title>
        <info>info 3</info>
    </news>
    <news>
        <date>Jan 04</date>
        <title>title 4</title>
        <info>info 4</info>
    </news>
</year></newsmodule>';


  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "year[name='2012']" );

$("body").append($($title).find("date").text());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HXLk4/13/)